# javascript function for get hours but starting at a hour and getting every x hour

Tags: javascript

This function mas have parameters (startingHour, everyXhours);

This function must return an array of hours allowed.

posible hours [0 1,2 ...22,23] array all the hours

want a function for get an array of all the hours allowed separates everyXhours

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to solve this? It looks like homework.

Comment: Sorry, I try, but not success. Not homework, is for use as a mask in a nodejs cron for run tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is pretty simple to do if you're not trying to be super elegant.  Brute force approach is to fill an array with possible values then filter out the ones you don't want.

```
function getHours(start, everyX) {
   const total = Array(24).fill().map((n, i) => { return i; });

   return total.filter((n) => {
     return (n === start || 
     ( n > start && n % everyX === 0));
   })
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3n7jeppp/1)

**UPDATE**

Ok based on your new requirements, it's still fairly simple. Instead of a pure filter, you would rotate the array first, and then take every nth item.

```
function getHours(start, everyX) {
   const all = Array(24).fill().map((n, i) => { return i; });
   all.unshift.apply(all, all.splice( start, all.length ) );

   return all.filter((n, i) => {
     return i % everyX === 0;
   })
}
```

Comment: Still I need the hours from the end then go to the start. The idea is starting in the hour selected but every x hour and get all the posible hour in a day. Must cover all hours in a day. Thank for your helpç

Comment: That's not what you asked for in the question.

Comment: sorry I know, very difficult write in English and a lot of hurry  too.

Comment: @user3749378, ok, have a try at that.

Comment: In last function you dont use start param. It is important because start hour for a task tell wich hour are allowed. Same param everyX but different start hour change the lis of hours

Comment: Sorry,this code works perfect, N is the start. This is correct. Thank you very much for your help